# String sequences with Ruby: Cloning and duplicating

Tags: ruby

So I've wrote this code but I can't seem to figure out how to write out the last piece of logic for it to work as desired.

```
def accum(s)
 s.upcase.split("").join("-")
end

#### pseudo #####
# for each character greater than x +1
# join using "-"
#capitalise the first letter
# print "MyStrings".methods.sort
```

Currently this is what my code returns:

```
Expected: "Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu",
 instead got: Z-P-G-L-N-R-X-Q-E-N-U
```

I've tried using .each_char and writing a block that adds +1 to chara but that didn't work =/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
def accum(str)
  str.each_char.with_index(1).map(&:*).map(&:capitalize).join('-')
end
```

Step by step:

```
'hello'
   .each_char         #=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
   .with_index(1)     #=> [["h", 1], ["e", 2], ["l", 3], ["l", 4], ["o", 5]]
   .map(&:*)          #=> ["h", "ee", "lll", "llll", "ooooo"]
   .map(&:capitalize) #=> ["H", "Ee", "Lll", "Llll", "Ooooo"]
   .join('-')         #=> "H-Ee-Lll-Llll-Ooooo"
```

It first retrieves each character along with its 1-based index. Next, the character-index pairs are combined via [`String#*`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#2A-method) to duplicate the characters (`"l" * 3` becomes `"lll"`). Finally, each part is capitalized and joined by `-`.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan very clean, very readable and very easy to understand. Legend!

Answer (score 1):

Another method, you can use 'each_with_index'.

```
def accum(s)
 s.upcase.split("").each_with_index.to_a.map{|x| x[0]+x[0].downcase*x[1]}.join("-")
end
```

Comment: thank you! looks quite complicated but I understand-ish.

Answer (score 0):

`s.split("").map{|x| "#{x.upcase}#{x.downcase*(s.index(x))}"}.join("-")`

This is what I came up with. However it will not work if there's repeating characters in the string as `.index(x)` returns the index of the first instance of x.

I suppose I'll leave that for you to do

Comment: Can you please check the expected input and output and check with your solution. Thanks!

Comment: I believe my solution does meet the expected solution stated

Comment: not sure why it's not passing all the tests. seems to be returning what is asked for: ```Expected: "J-Ii-Www-Pppp-Ccccc-Ssssss-Wwwwwww-Ssssssss-Lllllllll-Vvvvvvvvvv-Wwwwwwwwwww", instead got: "J-Ii-Www-Pppp-Ccccc-Ssssss-Www-Ssssssss-Lllllllll-Vvvvvvvvvv-Wwwwwwwwwww"```

Comment: ahh i see why.. there's a second case of w's that breaks the sequence ```-Ii-Www-Pppp-Ccccc-Ssssss-Www```